# Invalid resource attribute MytargetGroup for resource Outputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm looking to get arn output of the target group. What is the correct way? I've tried the following and it didn't work.

```html
  ### Target group ###

  MyTargetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: "200,302"
      Name: target-group-1
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 80
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      VpcId: !ImportValue vpc-id

  #### Outputs ####
  
  Outputs:
    MyTargetGroupOutput:
      Value: !GetAtt MyTargetGroup.TargetGroupArn
```

Errors

cfn-lint

```
[cfn-lint] E3001: Invalid resource attribute MyTargetGroupOutput for resource Outputs
```

Cloudformation

```
An API call to CloudFormation.UpdateStackSet (RequestId: f1581762-6a59-41eb-802e-9927f849a7be) returned a ValidationError error: Invalid template resource property 'MyTargetGroupOutput' (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: bf04faf2-9dee-4874-9069-7a41a5b4d503; Proxy: null)
```

According to this document, it should work as I have above, but it doesn't.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html

Comment: What version of cfn-lint are you using?

Comment: Works fine with `cfn-lint 0.76.2`

Comment: I thought cfn-lint was a problem as well and I proceeded with deploying through cloudformation and it is also throws an error. Here's my cfn-lint version
cfn-lint --version
cfn-lint 0.78.1

Comment: Does cloudformation throw the same error?

Comment: Invalid template resource property 'MyTargetGroupOutput'

Answer (score 1):

You have indentation problem. The `Outputs` section was placed in the same level with `Resources` fields, in this case, the `MyTargetGroup` field, etc

If you correct the indentation for `Outputs` section by removing 2 spaces on the left, it shall work.

Your snippet should looks like below:

```
  ### Target group ###

  MyTargetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: "200,302"
      Name: target-group-1
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 80
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      VpcId: !ImportValue vpc-id

#### Outputs ####
  
Outputs:
  MyTargetGroupOutput:
    Value: !GetAtt MyTargetGroup.TargetGroupArn
```